# Multiple markers at this line - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult((int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data))
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I actually took the above code from net and placed but am getting error like this:

Multiple markers at this line:

- Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
- Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
- void is an invalid type for the variable onActivityResult
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement

Comment: Looks like most of your syntax stuff has been handled below, but part of your error may be that onActivityResult is `protected`, not `public`.  It's important that the method signature be the same when using the @Override annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra parenthesis:

```
public void onActivityResult((int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data))
```

And try this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

Comment: "Same Error occuring" as Multiple markers at this line - void is an invalid type for the variable onActivityResult - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected

Comment: Somewhere above this line you have a typo (you are missing a ")", "}", or ";" etc) Please post you entire class.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra set of brackets in your method signature. Try using:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
public void onActivityResult((int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data))
```

Should be:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
```

Note the removal of the second set of parenthesis around the arguments to the method.

Comment: "Same Error occuring" as Multiple markers at this line - void is an invalid type for the variable onActivityResult - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses of the parameter specification are redundant. Try:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

### Edit

If you still get syntax errors, it would be helpful to paste the source code of the whole Activity class.

Comment: "Same Error occuring" as   Multiple markers at this line
 - void is an invalid type for the variable 
  onActivityResult
 - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected